# C# DataGridView rows are not displaying- Windows Form is broken

Tags: c#

Currently my form has a Datagirdview(DGV) that does not have any values inside the DGV when displayed.

The column headings had to be inserted manually after the code did not work, however, the exact code worked on an older project of mine.

Code (The DGV is called dgvQuestions):

```
        DataTable Test = new DataTable();

        Test.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
        Test.Columns.Add("Advice", typeof(string));
        Test.Columns.Add("Choice One", typeof(string));
        Test.Columns.Add("Choice Two", typeof(string));
        Test.Columns.Add("Choice Id (Determines Answer)", typeof(int));

        dgvQuestions.DataSource = Test;
```

I am not sure if the form is somewhat broken as I have never seen a DGV so challenging to insert data to.

To insert data the code I used was:

```
 dgvQuestions.Rows.Add(1, "2x2", "Count with your fingers", "4", "9", 1);
```

Does anyone know how to check if the DGV is locked and doesn't accept modifications? or just what the problem is...

--------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------

The code that has been defined as an answer did not work in my form, and textboxes values were constantly valued at "" despite there being characters inside the textbox. How do you fix a form that dosesn't accept inputs?

Comment: Given the apparent nature, rather than a DataTable you could use a collection like BindingList and life would be all kittens and rainbows

Comment: So... You are creating a DataTable and adding some columns to it (but no data).  Then you have a DGV, and you are setting its DataSource to your empty data table, but adding a row to the DGV (even though it has a data source). You need to pick either a) use data binding or b) add stuff manually.  In addition: why are you using a data table, why not a collection of strongly typed objects, for example?

Comment: I am not adding data to the grid yet, as the column headings will not work. The data will be extracted from a database and placed in the DGV. The code in the 'Answer' does not work on the  DGV inside the Form.

Comment: If you have a database it is not your job to put data in the datatable.  Use a DBCommand object or a DataAdapter to fill the table.  You are doing everything the hardest way possible

Comment: I have inserted the data from my database into lists (that are used in other forms) to make it more robust and work when the connection is down. The data is already inserted to the database and I don't understand how that even came up, nonetheless, the data grid view I have got to work before with roughly 12 lines of code, to insert the data once the headings have been fitted I just need to insert a for loop to iterate through the lists. I just can't get the headings to work, without manually inserting them, I suspect that the DGV in the form has editable locked or maybe I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

you should be adding rows to your `datatable` then assign that as `datasource` to `datagridview`

```
DataTable Test = new DataTable();

Test.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(string));
Test.Columns.Add("Advice", typeof(string));
Test.Columns.Add("Choice One", typeof(string));
Test.Columns.Add("Choice Two", typeof(string));
Test.Columns.Add("Choice Id (Determines Answer)", typeof(int));

Test.Rows.Add(1, "2x2", "Count with your fingers", "4", "9", 1);;

dgvQuestions.DataSource = Test;
```

As suggest by Disaffected.. in the comment of your question, you might want to  read up on using `BindingSource`.

Comment: I tried this method prior to assigning rows to the DGV and not the data table.I will look at BindingLists, thanks

Comment: @NodeCode, did you say in the comments in the question that your tables have different column names when you retrieve them from the database? it may be binding issue then.

Comment: Currently, the database is not being used, as the headings are not working. The entire form has been acting unexpectedly, I am going to test out the same code on another identical form and check the results. The form seemed to be locked.

Comment: The code works on another form...Can a Form be broken? I don't understand when the entire form is identical

Comment: Is it a new form or form with previously written code? Can you try something really simple and see how that behaves. Like- dgvQuestions.DataSource = new List<string>() {"a","b","c"}; Comment the datatable code for the time being.

Comment: Also, I didn't understand what you meant by 'form seems to be locked'. Did you mean it is frozen and you cant use any controls on that form?

Comment: The test code you gave me, resulted in an empty dgvQuestions. By the form being 'locked' I just mean that there are no inputs and outputs that are working, basically an unresponsive form.

Comment: I really want to help you solve this,wish there was way to see the code. Just a wild guess, is the correct datagridview being shown in the Form? What i mean is by any chance do you have more than one datagridview and we've been setting DataSource prop of the one that is not displayed in Form at all... I did sth similar once, so thought I would share..

Comment: Only one datagridview, but strangley the textboxes output is always " ", no matter what has been inserted. I dont understand how a Form can be broken as everything looks correct, I dont think you can send zip files of projects to stack overflow.

Comment: Just curious, whats stopping you from doing this in a new form? cant send zip from SO, but may be dropbox or github if it is your personal project and not from work.

Comment: I have changed to a new form now, I guess it is fine now however is a strange error, I have it on GitHub however the app cannot be run unless inside the campus I am working on due to the database connection and tables being saved to the server, thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome and I am happy that you were able to resolve the issue.  :)